I think I am been scammed and need help
I invested some money through the website haloporeth.xyz. After completing a 60-day staking period, they sent me instructions to unstake my earnings. However, they are asking for additional funds, and I'm unsure whether it's safe to proceed.
This is the smart contract they provided: 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7. I’ve also got the mining report they claimed was generated after the staking period expired Let me know if you need to see that.
If you have experience in identifying scams or verifying the legitimacy of such platforms, could you please help me determine if this is trustworthy?

The address you provided is tether token, not any deposit address. It sounds like a common scam, there shouldn't be any waiting period, and you shouldn't be speaking to someone who asks for more money.

this is  my wallet address if this help you to see the trail 0x2CAdBDc9124F4E1E9fb6C897E577ccd59316B543. also if you look at the website they did the stake as usdt that what the sent to my account as a reward

Looks like a complete scam. On deposit you get something called Coinbase Wallet ETH. As if Coinbase give you a token when you deposit to the exchange. When people call exit they get a "virtual share" token.
The contracts aren't verified to look at the implementation of the functions but
the deployer addresses are both funded by a random wallets that fund lots of other wallets. Common scammer tactic to fund wallets from from an initial scam, while relaying funds around to leave a long track for sec tools to follow. Can see eth go to vshare contract, but never see any withdrawn.
